# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I've just edited my XML, I've put slide menu code in  my XML, but there is an error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/menu_content_menulist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"

        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@null"/>      
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.mozaik.tangsel.side_menu_scroll.ScrollerLinearLayout       
            android:id="@+id/menu_content_side_slide_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"        
            android:orientation="verti_

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_statis"        
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_app"
         >

        <include layout="@layout/layout_action_bar" />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" 
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/inbox_interface"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ImageMozaikTangsel"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dip" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabMozaikTangselLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

   </LinearLayout>
</com.mozaik.tangsel.side_menu_scroll.ScrollerLinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error in logcat:

```
  10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.findRoots(RelativeLayout.java:1352)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1299)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:316)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:337)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2217)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15193)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4216)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
10-26 15:53:32.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10869):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like you're modifying the `LayoutParams` in code. XML layout alone won't cause this. So, include relevant code in the question.

Comment: Make sure you import the correct LayoutParams.

Comment: my error solved with @kalyan pvs's answer, thank for you too :)

Comment: need help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951608/java-lang-classcastexception-android-view-viewgrouplayoutparams-cannot-be-cast

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your code you are importing `import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;` instead of `android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams`

so Delete `import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;`

and Add `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams`

Comment: Why would ViewGroup.LayoutParams make a difference?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky because LayoutParams is a inner class of particular classes..RelativeLayout extend ViewGroup so you can typecast but RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  can not extend ViewGroup.LayoutParams so it will throw ClassCastException

Answer (score 5):

You should make the LayoutParams object of the parent layout. Example in the layout below to set height and width of the LinearLayout you have to make the LayoutParmas of RelativeLayout not LinearLayout itself.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".newsblog.NewsDetailsActivity"
    >

      <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
//IN ACTIVITY
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30,30); //Parent Params
linearLayout.setLayoutParmas(params); //Child Layout


//If you want to set the params of the Relative Layout above. It seems it doesn't have any parent but it has a parent created by android framework which is a frame layout. So 
FrameLayout.LayoutParmas params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParmas(30, 30);//FrameLayout is a parentcreated by anroid frame work
relativeLayout.setLayoutParmas(params);  ////Here Relative layout is child
```

Answer (score 0):

just click <kbd>Cnt+o</kbd> for delete unwanted imports

Answer (score 0):

Use code below:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(
  new android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewPager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewPager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Do let me know if you face any error.

Answer (score 0):

**

> To Set RecyclerView Margin Programatically In Android

**

```
MarginLayoutParams mp = (MarginLayoutParams) myRecyclerView.getLayoutParams();
                mp.setMarginStart(0);
                mp.setMarginEnd(0);
                //mp.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
```